# Replace content in different div with onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make page that has a list of store locations on the left side, and a div on the left side that shows the stores location and hours.

This is different per store, so I'm trying to make the content in the div on the right side show the information that matches the store that you click on the left side of the page. [This is what I currently have](http://jsfiddle.net/43rB6/), and it's not very good yet.

Right now, it's just a simple hover, and it worked fine. But I am running into a new problem: The text disappears as soon as your mouse leaves "store 1"

I tried to solve this by using an onClick event, but this shows the info for store 1 in the div, and I don't know how to replace it with the info for store 2 if you would click the link for store 2. ([something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/vzmnJ/1866/), which is not working at all)

```
function showDiv1() {
    document.getElementById('store1').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('rood').style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function showDiv2() {
    document.getElementById('store1').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('rood').style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

So basically I have two questions.

1: How do I replace the content in the div on the right side once you click on a store on the left side.

2: There HAS to be an easier solution. There just has to be. Could anyone suggest a different approach to take here?

I've wasted an entire morning on this so far, so any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/modaloda/EB53V/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the content in div, you can use

```
 document.getElementById('store1').innerHTML='your text content';
```

updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vzmnJ/1879/

Comment: I have seen this answer before, but I need an example to understand it. I create a function with this code, and then it just shows the content in my div?

Comment: Added fiddle demo, please check

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a function for each div, I suggest using a function that can handle all divs.

```
    <div id="zweef" onmouseover="javascript:showdetail('<p>some detail here</p>')">
store 1</div>

    function showdetail(detail){
        document.getElementById('fiets').innerHTML=detail;
    }
```